# Unable to concatenate features to same shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am embedding a text document using the following code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization

# Model constants.
MAX_FEATURES = 10000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 128
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 1000

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
    max_tokens=MAX_FEATURES,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
)

vectorize_layer.adapt(docs)


text_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)

vectorized_text = vectorize_layer(text_input)

x = layers.Embedding(MAX_FEATURES+1, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)(vectorized_text)
```

After the embedding layer I would like to attach further features - this is a one hot encoded numpy array, which contains 11 cols and a row per sample.

```py
one_hot_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 11), dtype='float32')
x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, one_hot_input])
```

I have tried various combinations for the concatenation axis and also for the shape, but with no luck.

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 1000, 128), (None, 1, 11)]
```

The model will compile when setting the following params:

```
one_hot_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 11), dtype='float32')
x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, one_hot_input])
```

But will throw an error when running `fit()`:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node functional_30/concatenate_36/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](functional_30/dropout_54/dropout/Mul_1, functional_30/Cast, functional_30/concatenate_36/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,1000,128], [?,11], [].
```

EDIT:

Here is the compiling but failing model summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_68 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
text_vectorization_2 (TextVecto (None, 1000)         0           input_68[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_56 (Embedding)        (None, 1000, 128)    1280128     text_vectorization_2[20][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_64 (Dropout)            (None, 1000, 128)    0           embedding_56[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_69 (InputLayer)           [(None, None, 11)]   0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_44 (Concatenate)    (None, 1000, 139)    0           dropout_64[0][0]                 
                                                                 input_69[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)                (None, 1000, 139)    19460       concatenate_44[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_65 (Dropout)            (None, 1000, 139)    0           dense_23[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)             (None, 1000, 1)      140         dropout_65[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,299,728
Trainable params: 1,299,728
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: The dimensions for your two tensors/numpy arrays are totally different and do not match along any dimension. So, you cannot concatenate them

Comment: Yes, concatenate is possible only on specific cases, it just won't work in other cases.